# apply a jquery event to a css shape

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made an unordered list that I have set to respond to a jQuery function that changes the type from the colour black to white. When positioning the type i set each a tag as a separate class for the list options ex: .home,.about, etc. After each option i included a css shape by using .home:after and putting in the relevant details for the shape

My question is there a way to apply a jQuery function to these shapes as well even though they are not referenced in the HTML and use the same class name as the a tags.

```js
$(function(){ //start of jQuery

  "use strict";

  $('#menu').hover(function(){ /*selects the menu li only if it has a child ul (sub-menu) and adds the hover event */

    $(this).find('ul').toggle();    /* selects the ul inside the li that has been rolled over and toggles the display on/off */

  });

});
```

```css
.table{
  padding-top: 702px;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#menu{
  min-width: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -41px;
}

#menu li{
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
}
/* formating for type on navigation bar*/
a{  
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Arial";
  color: white;
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 900;
}

#menu a:hover{
  color: #000000;   
}

.home{
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: -694px;
}

/* start of parallelogram */
.home:after{            
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 138px;
  height: 38px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-45deg);
  background: black;
  margin-top: 0px;
  left: -410px;
  top: -9px;
  z-index: -1;
}
/* end of parallelogram*/

.about{
  margin-left: -370px;  
}

/* start of parallelogram */
.about:after{
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 138px;
  height: 38px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-45deg);
  background: black;
  margin-top: 0px;
  left: -250px;
  top: -9px;
  z-index: -1;
}                       
/* end of parallelogram*/

.work{
  margin-left: -62px;   
}

/* start of parallelogram */
.work:after{            
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 138px;
  height: 38px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-45deg);
  background: black;
  margin-top: 0px;
  left: -92px;
  top: -9px;
  z-index: -1;
}                       
/* end of parallelogram*/

.skills{
  margin-left: 95px;
}
/* start of parallelogram */
.skills:after{          
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 138px;
  height: 38px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-45deg);
  background: black;
  margin-top: 0px;
  left: 66px;
  top: -9px;
  z-index: -1;
}   
/* end of parallelogram*/

.contact{
  margin-left: 244px;
}

/* start of parallelogram */
.contact:after{         
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 38px;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-45deg);
  background: black;
  margin-top: 0px;
  left: 224px;
  top: -9px;
  z-index: -1;
}                       
/* end of parallelogram*/
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="table">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="home">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="about">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="work">WORK</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="skills">SKILLS</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="contact">CONTACT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>     
</div>
```

Comment: Just a note i changed the shapes to black and the type to white so it would be visible.

Comment: then please update the snippets accordingly also try to format `HTML`, `js` and `CSS` with proper indentation.